# Testing locale on Ubuntu using setlocale() and gettext()

Tags: c, linux, locale

I am trying to write a program that prints an English message in French based on locale.

I wrote the following sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libintl.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    char *str = setlocale(LC_ALL, "fr_FR.UTF-8");
    if(str == NULL)
        printf("setlocale() cannot be honored");
    else
        printf("setlocale() return = %s \n", str);

    bindtextdomain("helloworld","/usr/share/locale");
    textdomain("helloworld");
    printf("%s", gettext("Hello!\n"));

    return 0; 
}
```

I checked the file `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED` and can see `fr` is there:

```
fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8
fr_FR ISO-8859-1
fr_FR@euro ISO-8859-15
```

I also tried running `sudo locale-gen fr-FR.UTF-8`. When I run `locale` on the command line, I see:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

When I run my program, `setlocale()` returns `NULL`. Can anyone tell what I'm missing ?

**Edit**

When trying to for `zh-CN`, I also checked the contents of directory `/usr/share/locale/zh-CN/LC_MESSAGES`. The following listing appears:

```
apt.mo              gnome-panel-3.0.mo  iso_639.mo
debconf.mo          iso_15924.mo        language-selector.mo
dpkg.mo             iso_3166_2.mo       libapt-inst1.4.mo
e2fsprogs.mo        iso_3166.mo         libapt-pkg4.12.mo
example-content.mo  iso_4217.mo         update-notifier.mo
ghex-3.0.mo         iso_639_3.mo        xdg-user-dirs.mo
```

Comment: what does `locale -a` show?

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk It doesn't contain `fr-FR`. What does that mean ? Language is not installed on the system ?

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk I tried a language from the list printed by `locale -a`. I tried `zh_CN.utf8`. `setlocale()` returns the same string, but `gettext()` still prints `Hello!`. Do my `bindtextdomain()` and `textdomain()` calls have a problem ?

Comment: Just zh_CN doesn't work, because its not in the `locale -a` list perhaps ?

Comment: good. it works then. Hello is returned because you do not understand the concept of locale: it is not google translate; dictionary probably doesn't have translation for work Hello! Try this example instead: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clocale/setlocale/

Comment: Ok. If I have to run the program on someone else's machine, should I also have some way to edit the dictionary ?

Comment: You probably want to add own *.mo for your program. Google knows a lot about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `locale -a` doesn't show fr_FR locale, you do not have one installed on your system.

The best/easiest way to do it may slightly depends on the distro. This topic answers your question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/76013/how-do-i-add-locale-to-ubuntu-server